# I need to be able to type into the ComboBox without it causing a SelectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox which acts as a list of profiles. When the user clicks the drop down list, and selects a profile, it loads settings based on that profile. I want the user to be able to modify the settings, and save them as their own profile. To do that, I want them to name their profile by typing into the ComboBox. The problem is, while typing, the SelectionChanged event is triggering, causing any profiles with similar names to load. I need the user to be able to type into the combobox, without it selecting one of the items. Or, I need to make the code that is triggered on SelectionChanged event only trigger when the user has selected an item by clicking it on the drop down box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a local bool variable m_dontHandleSelection and set it to true before you update the combo in yore code behind.

that way you can check it in the SelectionChanged handler and return without doing anything,
except setting the boolean to false

Comment: Thanks! That was a super simple solution. Not sure why I didn't think of it. I set the bool variable to true every time the ComboBox's KeyDown event was triggered, that way even though a SelectionChanged event will still be triggered, I can test and only run my code when the bool is false. Then I can simply set the bool to false again at the end of the SelectionChanged event, so that the user would still be able to select a profile from the list, even after typing. (For example, if they start typing a name for their profile, and change their mind and select a different profile instead)

Comment: Crap, I just thought of something though. What if the user types in something that doesn't trigger the SelectionChanged, as it only triggers that if the text partially matches one of the combobox items. Because then the bool will be set to true, and the user won't be able to select an item from the drop down list.

Comment: I figured it out. Set the bool to false on KeyUp